# CreateDirectory fails with permission denied

Tags: c

I am running one dll under window C# application. APP call dll api for all the transaction with the system.
While I try for creating directory at C# app level it creates successfully but the calls fail with permission denied if dll calls createDirectory method. Process has full control permission.

................
code snippet
................

```
int dlnaFileSystemNewDirPeer(char *in_name)
{
    int len = dlna_strlen(in_name);
    wchar_t sbuff[100];
    swprintf(sbuff, len, L"%p", in_name);
    int ret = CreateDirectory(sbuff, NULL);
    int err = GetLastError();
    if (err) {
        printf("CreateDirectory fails with error:%d\n", err);
        return err;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`swprintf(sbuff, len, L"%p", in_name);`

You try to create the directory `0x1324000` (or whatever the address of your `in_name` is).

Use `%S` (note the uppercase `S`) or `%ws`, depending on the runtime you are linking against.

See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647550(VS.85).aspx) if you are using Visual studio.